# Chart.js - the exact distance in pixels between the grid lines along the X axis

Tags: charts

1. How can I set **distance between ticks** on x-Axis in pixels? I have to set this distance exactly 54px

[image]

2. How can I set **different width of all chart** depending on data length?
   For example if I have only 2 values, my width should be 54px+54px + paddings
   And if I have 20 values - my chart width should be 54px*20 + paddings

Answer (score 0):

I have to count data length, multiply 54px to this value and add padding.
Then I have to set canvas wrapper width to this value.

```
var count_data_length = chart_data.length;
$(".canvas-wrapper").width(54*count_data_length+100);
```